# In Linux, how do i prevent users from executing chown, chgrp or chmod?

Tags: linux, command-line

In Linux, how can I prevent users from executing chown, chgrp or chmod?

Answer (score 4):

`chown`: Already requires root.

`chgrp`: Users can only change into groups they themselves belong to.

`chmod`: Probably impossible to restrict - unless you also block all programming language compilers/interpreters and disable any remote filesystem access (including SFTP).

(It *might* be possible to block the `chmod()` syscall with something like AppArmor (if it can block syscalls *at all*), but it would break a whole lot of programs.)

Answer (score 1):

try using [Iron Bars Shell](http://ibsh.sourceforge.net/)

> *"Iron Bars Shell (ibsh) is a free,
>   open-source restricted system shell
>   for Linux and Unix. It is small,
>   secure, and is based on a whole new
>   perspective: DENY EVERYTHING!! If
>   something is needed, allow it."*

it basicly denies everything, and then you allow users to use what you want